# Search content based on Parent node id or the current id of the page in Umbraco

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I would like to implement a search functionality, but not the entire site search. Instead, search contents based on the node id .

for example the below is search code

```
  @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
 <form action="/intranetsearchresult/" method="GET">
        <input type="text" class="searchfield" placeholder="" name="query">
        <button class="searchbtn btn btn-default btn-sm">Search</button>
    </form>
    
     @{
        var searchQuery = Request.QueryString["query"];
    
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery))    
        {
            <div class="searchresults">
                <p class="intro-para">Your search results for <strong>"@searchQuery"</strong></p>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var result in Umbraco.Search(searchQuery))
                    {
                        if(!@result.SearchResultsHide){
                            <li>
                                <a class="heading1 inline-link" href="@result.Url">@result.Name</a>
                                <div  class="heading2">Created Date : @result.CreateDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
                                <div  class="heading2">Updated Date : @result.updateDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
                            </li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
         }
    }
```

from the above `Umbraco.Search(searchQuery)` this will search the entire website inside content.

Is there any way that I can search like this

```
Umbraco.Search(searchQuery , "Nodeid")
```

for example

```
 Umbraco.Search("home loans, "1011")
```

like this?